# error while exporting module in module-info.java -> Package is empty: projects

Tags: java, gradle, java-module, java-platform-module-system, module-info

Before continuing, take a look on the image below:
[image]

Any thoughts on why I'm unable to export the same module as my declared module in the module-info.java?

P.S: The highlighted error message has nothing to do with this topic. But if you have any hint on this error, try answering [this stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67406057/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-boot-layer-java-lang-module-findexceptio)

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight correction, you can use the `exports` directive **for packages** and **not modules**. The declaration syntax is detailed in [JLS7.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7) as

```
exports PackageName [to ModuleName {, ModuleName}] ;
```

Other few lines of your code(consisting of `exports ...`) comply with the behavior and seems to be compiling. The reason for the failure on the mentioned line is because the package `projects` is empty and empty packages are not allowed to be exported by the java module system.